# Whats the difference between 'rb' and 'rU' in the open() function for csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I was wondering what the difference between:

```
with codecs.open('xxxx.csv', 'rU') as h:
```

and

```
with codecs.open('xxxx.csv', 'rb') as h:
```

I think I remember someone saying you should use '**rb**' and not '**rU**' when I started my project with reading .csv files, but I cant seem to find it again.

Anybody who would like to explain this?
Thanks

Comment: You *did* read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open), right?

Comment: @deceze Wow! Here I was thinking this was the place to get an more simpler explenation for those of us that aren't quite that good with this stuff. Guess I'm the fool. Thanks anyways

Comment: You can well get an explanation if you need one, but for that we'd at least need to know what you *don't* know. The difference is plainly documented. If you don't understand the documentation for some reason or another, give us some details that we can expand on. As is we would start regurgitating the existing documentation, which is not very useful to anyone.

Comment: The thing is, using 'rU' has worked for me so far, but I remebered reading a few times here that you should use 'rb' instead and was simply wondering why. @deceze

Comment: Maybe point to the source of that claim then. In general terms, that is not a correct recommendation, but perhaps it covers some specific scenario where this is actually useful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) states, `U` (Universal Newlines) mode is deprecated; you should not use it anymore. Instead use the `newline=` keyword argument.

[The `csv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) states that it prefers that parameter to be `''`, so `open` won't do any interpretation of newlines and leave that up to the `csv` module.

Since you likely want to decode your CSV into *text* (not bytes), it makes no real sense to open them in `b` (binary) mode.

Bottomline: the usual way to parse CSV files is:

```
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        ...
```

This means you're using the implicit `open` mode `rt`, for reading in text mode. Unless you have very special needs, this is probably what you want. And the above sample code is taken straight from the documentation.